# How to hide the outer parents in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Below is my code, my goal is when the user click the `<a>` which is in 'child_2', I want to hide $(this) class="parent". How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child_1">
    </div>

    <div class="child_2">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Click Me</a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="child_3">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear..What you want to do exacly.. Can you be more specific?

Comment: If you hide a parent div it will hide all subsequent children within that parent. If that is the case it would be simple to just add a function that hides it. $('.child_2 a').click(function() { $('.parent').hide();};

Comment: You could read the jQuery documentation for 5 minutes and get the answer to this. Here is a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ce4Ym/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('.parent').hide();
```

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: That was fast, thanks it works. I'll accept the answer in 12 min

Comment: @user2310422 12 mins passed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line: `$('.child_2 a').click(function() {$(this).parent().hide()});`

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce4Ym/3/)

This will hide the parent element of whichever link you click.

Comment: I am trying to depend on $(this) since I have multiple '.parent' class. I DO NOT want to hide them all. Only the one that is clicked

Comment: Updated it again, now the answer is a lot cleaner, the HTML is a lot cleaner, the script works perfectly, and it better shows off the hiding of individual elements.

Comment: This will hide only $(this)'s parent which is the <li>, the original parent of <a>. it will ignore the class="parent", class="child_1", class="child_2", class="child_3". THose are the outer parents I want to hide as well

Comment: What is it that you want? I guess the question wasn't clear. What do you want hidden when you press the link. Make a JSFiddle showing it. (For future reference, always make a JSFiddle when asking questions about HTML, CSS, or Javascript it makes it easier for everyone and properly displays the problem and allowed people to easily and adequately demonstrate fixes.)

Comment: Claudio Redi has the prefect answer I am looking for

Comment: I was wondering as well since I already stated 1 min after I asked that his code works.

Comment: I'm tired of questions I know the answers to always being answered before I can finish writing my answer and then their answer gets all the upvotes and accepts and all my work goes nowhere

Comment: Especially when I worked hard on mine and he already has 19k. Ugh.

Comment: Aren't you learning during the process? Of course! These people were just like you. They are so familiar with the code that it became a second nature to them. Always pay attention on their answer, so when someone ask a similar question, you can answer correctly and faster than before.

Comment: Actually, I was like that, I've just been away from web design for like a year. This question was what I needed to remind myself how jQuery works =p